# Android ICS Style checkboxes (and other widgets)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I want my checkboxes to look like default 4.x Ice Cream Sandwich style checkboxes do (when I run my app on ICS)

What I've already tried was to define a style like

```
<style name="LightThemeSelector" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"> 
</style>
```

and apply it to the checkbox in my layout, which didn't make any difference.

What am I doing wrong?

thank you!

Comment: for ICS style use (Theme).DeviceDefault.(Light)

Comment: It doesn't seem like you're applying your style inside the application tag in your Manifest.